# How can I make the two cubes to stop when colliding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Or making them bounce when colliding. but now it's not detecting any collision.

The first cube have a Rigidbody Use Gravity and Is Kinematic both checked enabled true.
If I will disable the Is Kinematic the cube will fall down.
Both cubes have attached the same script.
Both cubes have a box collider and the Is Trigger on both is unchecked disabled.

This script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Each cube have the script and target is the other cube. So both cubes are moving to each other but never collide.

Both cubes settings screenshot :

[image: Cubes settings]

Comment: Look into `OnTriggerEnter`, you can't expect anything to happen if you don't code it....

Comment: Maybe you are doing wrong. If you want to use physic (bouncing for exemple) you could just make a script who change the rigidbody.velocity to always move in direction of the other. Then Unity physic will handle the collision and bounce.
Use a Physical material to change the bounciness.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better practice set `rigidbody.velocity` once instead of changing `transform.position` every frame, but this solution should work regardless:

```cs
private bool collided = false;

private void Move() {
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}

private void Update() {
    if (!collided) {
        Move();
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Door>() != null) {
        collided = true;
    }
}
```

This may not be the best way to do it depending on how you plan on moving forward, but this is a way that works.

If you want to make them bounce, I'd suggest using `rigidbody.AddForce()` or set `rigidbody.velocity`. Then you can either use a bouncy physic material or changing the `OnCollisionEnter` code to use `rigidbody.AddForce()` or `rigidbody.velocity` when they collide with each other.